# Webshim for inputs with changing type

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker, webshim

If i use webshim to enhance firefox with a datepicker, i have some problems with dynamic content: 
if i change the type of the input, webshim does not update the widget itself. if i use the method updatePolyfill the widget will not be replaced, but added to the input.

```
    var $input = this.$ele.find("input");        
    $input.attr("placeholder", this.options.placeholder.value);
    $input.attr("name", inputName);
    $input.attr("type",this.options.datatype.value);
```

a date input looks like there are not 1 datepicker icon, but 1 for every update call.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

toggle the webshim element

```
var $input = this.$ele.find("input"); 
$input.attr("type","date");
$input.updatePolyfill()
$('.ws-date').show();$input.hide()
```

When the type changes,

```
$('.ws-date').hide();$input.show()
```